# default option in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, default

I'm currently researched in the compiler options of msvc. there are some problems with it. for example, the option ***/GR*** that is depicted as a ***default*** option.However, I cannot perceive that option is default for IDE or command line. may someone give a definitive interpretation to this.

Comment: It's default for the both. IDE does not set it by default and lets cl.exe to apply its defaults.